# How can I make two windows on jetpack compose desktop and going from window to another?

Tags: kotlin, desktop-application, compose-desktop

How can I make two windows on jetpack compose desktop and going from window to another when I click button for example?

```
fun main() = application {
    Window(
        onCloseRequest = ::exitApplication,
        title = "Products Manager",
        state = rememberWindowState(width = 700.dp, height = 600.dp)
    ) {
        val count = remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
        MaterialTheme {
            Column(Modifier.fillMaxSize(), Arrangement.spacedBy(5.dp)) {
                Button(modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally),
                    onClick = {
                        count.value++
                    }) {
                    Text(if (count.value == 0) "Hello World" else "Clicked ${count.value}!")
                }
                Button(modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally),
                    onClick = {
                        count.value = 0
                    }) {
                    Text("Reset")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

To create multiple windows, you simply need to have multiple `Window` composables. Check out [Open and close multiple windows](https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-jb/tree/master/tutorials/Window_API_new#open-and-close-multiple-windows) documentation section for example.

To switch between windows programmatically, you can use `window.toFront()` on the window that should become topmost: `window` is property available in `FrameWindowScope` inside `Window.content`.

Here's an example how it can be done with two window "types". You can replace type with any other identifier.

```
enum class WindowTypes {
    First,
    Second,
}

fun main() = application {
    val windowFocusRequestSharedFlow = remember { MutableSharedFlow<WindowTypes>() }

    WindowTypes.values().forEach { windowType ->
        key(windowType) {
            Window(
                title = windowType.toString(),
                onCloseRequest = ::exitApplication,
            ) {
                LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
                    windowFocusRequestSharedFlow
                        .filter { it == windowType }
                        .collect {
                            window.toFront()
                        }
                }
                val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
                Button({
                    scope.launch {
                        val windowTypeToFocus = WindowTypes.values().run {
                            get((indexOf(windowType) + 1) % count())
                        }
                        windowFocusRequestSharedFlow.emit(windowTypeToFocus)
                    }
                }) {
                    Text("next window")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This approach works as long as there is at least one window initially visible. If you start out with no windows visible, seemingly adding one window state to the list doesn't trigger recomposition. Standalone example: https://gist.github.com/hakanai/a9ec53c015c54b7de10729e75fa05069

Comment: @Hakanai this may be a bug, you can [report](https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-multiplatform/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+sort%3Aupdated-desc) it